# Label text based on the locale

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts, jstl

I want to display the label name depending on the Locale (like English or French).

I have two properties file:

messages.properties:
`customer.name=Name`

messages_fr.properties:
`customer.name=Nom`

I have an array list in a Java class. In this list I want to store the values depending on the locale:
`arraylist.add(new ListItem("CustomerName", "<s:text name="customer.name"/>"));`

When I retrieve the value on jsp like this:
`<s:param name="prefix" value="'CustomerName'" />`

I have not implement this yet.

Am I going the right direction? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a standard approach, but that functionality is already built into pretty much every web framework you could use, and also into Struts. Here's a link to the [Localization section from the Struts 2 docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/localization.html).

*Edit:* Looking at your question again, this time actually reading it... what is the list for? No, that won't work. Simply put this in your JSP:

```
<s:text name="customer.name"/>
```

That renders the proper label depending on the locale of the user, no extra work required. Users with a French locate will see "Nom", everyone else "Name".

Comment: i have simply used <s:text name="customer.name" /> on display.jsp. but it does not take the effect. 
should i use array list task as described above to store the customer name so that i can find key value (customer name) on display.jsp ..?

Comment: please check this question:                                           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912029/activity-display-dynamically-depend-on-the-locale-on-struts-2